# Validate machine user credentials fails when the user has no password

Tags: c#, .net, windows, userprincipal

I'm trying to validate a username and its password on a local windows machine.

```
bool AreUserCredentialsValid(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        using(var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
        {
            return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password); 
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works fine for most cases. In one case I get the following error message.

> The user cannot login because of an account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy.

This message appears only if I login as user `A` and try to validate the credentials of user `A`. If I login as user `B` and try to validate the credentials of user `A` it works as expected.

I can reproduce this behavoir with the following cmd line.

```
runas /user:A notepad
```

How can I validate credentials of a local user in any case without changing system settings or the user? As the user is able to login it should be possible.

Comment: Have you tested the account and checked it is actually valid? What about if you view it via the Computer Management snap-in, anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: https://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-fix-logon-failure-user-account-restriction/

Comment: @pmcilreavy The account is valid, I can login with it. Ill take a look at the snap in. And I would like to validate the credentials without changing system settings. Windows seems able to do so too. My goal would be to do the same as windows when you login.

Comment: @pmcilreavy There is nothing in the log

Comment: what does it return if you pass `null, null` as username and password?

Comment: @Albert `true`. But I want to validate the credentials also when the given credentials are the same as the user of the current app domain.